# Como listar a sinopse das classes?

Tags: python, classes

Comecei a me aventurar no python e estou fazendo programa que lista a propriedades das classes. Bem uso o obj.**dic**, o help(obj), e o dir(obj). Alguém sabe se existe um comando que lista as sinopses dos métodos, algo mais ou menos assim:

Por exemplo para um Gtk.Box, alguém como obter um resultado semelhante a isto?

```
  pack_start(child, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
  pack_end(child, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
  pack_start_defaults(widget)
  pack_end_defaults(widget)
  pack_end_defaults(widget)
```

Comment: não é resposta ao que perguntas mas, por exemplo após `import math`,  `help(math.sin)`  ou na linha de comando `pydoc  math.sin` pode ajudar...

Comment: Tudo bem, isso eu consigo. Por acaso não sabe como fazer o help passar o texto para uma variavel string, em vez de impri-lo? Assim facilmente poderia localizar a parte que interessa com o String.find(texto_de_interesse).

Comment: Não sei bem :( -- normalmente o que tu queres está em `math.f.__doc__` para todas os simbolos relevantes  `f` em `dir(math)`

Answer (score 2):

Como está nos comentários - o texto que é exibido quando se pede o `help` em Python é o que é definido nos módulos, classes ou funções como  "docstring" - ele fica isponível como o  atributo `__doc__` do objeto em questão, e é criada automaticamente se a  primeira expressão dentro do corpo de um módulo, classe ou função (incluindo método) for uma string:

```
In [6]: import math

In [7]: math.sin.__doc__
Out[7]: 'sin(x)\n\nReturn the sine of x (measured in radians).'
```

Entretanto, nem sempre os objetos incluem uma docstring significativa - e nem sempre ela é o suficiente. O help do Python para classes, por exemplo, junta todas as declarações de métdos, e as docstrings de cada um, além da docstring da classe.

Internamente, o help utiliza o módulo `pydoc`, e, lá dentro, a função que recupera o texto completo da ajuda se chama `render_doc`.

Portanto:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> import pydoc
>>> text = pydoc.render_doc(gtk.Box)
>>> print (text)
...
```

Entretanto - mesmo o enderdoc não recupera a assinatura das funções que são escritas em C, ou se elas usam o recurso *args, **kwargs. É o caso da maior parte das funções do PyGTK - então não é possível rer uma saída como a que você pede.